# Sort the content of a DataTable according to a TextBox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to select my DataGridView's Rows by putting the value I'm looking for in a textbox. Also I would like the most identical value to be focused on / selected.
I already tried using the rowfilter function, which gave me this:

```
(dgv_DetailComptes.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Champ LIKE '%{0}%'", tbx_champ_Cpt.Text);
```

However, it filters the rows, meaning the other rows disapear when their content isn't the one I'm looking for. I would like to keep the rows in my table, and select the rows containing the value I'm looking for.
Also, my DGV takes it's Rows / Columns / values from a data Table so that might prevent me from using my DataGridView's row's index to search for the row containing the value.

Is there a way to select my rows this way ?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What is your definition of _most identical values_?

Comment: For example in {12, 123}, if I type "12", it will focus 12 first, but still highlight the others

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to find, doing maybe some useless stuff I don't know.
here's the code:

```
        private void tbx_champ_Cpt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbx_champ_Cpt.Text.ToString() == "")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_DetailComptes.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dgv_DetailComptes.Rows[i].Selected = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tbx_champ_Cpt.SelectionStart = tbx_champ_Cpt.Text.Length;
            tbx_champ_Cpt.Text = tbx_champ_Cpt.Text.ToString().ToUpper();
            DataTable d = (DataTable)dgv_DetailComptes.DataSource;
            String text = tbx_champ_Cpt.Text.ToString();
            DataRow[] row = d.Select("Champ like '%" + text + "%'");
            List<int> listeIndex = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_DetailComptes.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataRow r in row)
                {
                    if (((DataRowView)dgv_DetailComptes.Rows[i].DataBoundItem).Row == r)
                    {
                        dgv_DetailComptes.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                        listeIndex.Add(i);
                    }
                    else if (!listeIndex.Contains(i))
                    {
                        dgv_DetailComptes.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (dgv_DetailComptes.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
        {
        dgv_DetailComptes.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv_DetailComptes.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        }
    }
```